# How do i parse out this string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok so i have this string

```
Something 06/15/2009 some other data  33 77
```

And I want to seperate then like this

```
Something
06/15/2009
some other data  
33 
77
```

Any idea a clean way to do this

Comment: Are there always two numbers at the end, or can there be more or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
/(.+?)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/
```

[Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/u1MPpHM7id)

Gives what you want for the example given at least.

**Update:**

It might be better to make the .+ parts greedy:

```
/(.+)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(.+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/
```

This way, 'something' or 'some other data' can include dates and numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I would use regex (or split it by spaces?).

Here's a quick regex that split it up for you

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\/]*\s)
```

http://rubular.com/r/qWVj3yr3aw

Edit: didn't notice the one piece of data with spaces.  You can still use regex you just need to clarify where one "column" of data starts and ends.

Here's an EXACT match for the data if that's what you're looking for (Although there are better ways considering this statement isn't very useful if "some other data" changes..)

```
(\w+)\s([\w\/]+)\s(some other data)\s\s(\d*)\s(\d*)
```

http://rubular.com/r/yNEBNKq97N

Comment: @dcbarans Thanks for the rubular link, +1 - what a great tool :)

Comment: That matched on 6 or 7 different things and not the 5 that i need plus some other data are three separate matches...which will not work

Comment: @Trace You need to clarify what "some other data" is.  how many words? how long can it be?  Otherwise, i can't refine the query

Comment: @dcbarans - thanks for your help on this one ....i need "some other data" to be one match....so maybe we can do a regex looking for the next number and break there....not sure if that is possible

Comment: this did the trick /(.+?)\s+(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/

Comment: @Trace Glad you found the answer.  You should mark that reply from Justin Ko as correct then :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is `some_string.split(" ")`, to get an array of the substrings.

```
"Something 06/15/2009 some other data  33 77".split(" ")
=> ["Something", "06/15/2009", "some", "other", "data", "33", "77"]
```